# Cannot Access My Crypto Wallet ( It’s Not the Seed Phrase), maybe derivation path?

Tags: blockchain, address, wallet-recovery, mnemonic-seed, seed

*Requirement: Recover crypto*

What I possess: I have a **12 word** seed phrase, (Though I am not exactly sure of the organization that generated it).

I have the public address through which (blockchain.com explorer) I was able to determine the *address format*: **Base58 (P2PKH)**. Through it was able to determine that the address do possess some bitcoin. But I don't have any information regarding the **derivation path**

To summaries the info:

What I have:

1. 12-word Seed Phrase
2. Public Address
3. Address format

What I don't have:

1. Derivation Path
2. Private Key
3. Organization associated

What I tried:

I did a bit tinkering around with Electrum (through these guide: https://bitcoinelectrum.com/restoring-your-standard-wallet-from-seed/ https://bitcoinelectrum.com/restoring-your-multibithd-wallet-in-electrum/)

The checksum of *BIP-39 outputted*: **OK**; Off course, subsequently chose the address type: legacy (P2PKH) In conjunction to trying some default paths, I tried the "Detect existing accounts" which checked the common paths but to no avail

Recovery would be ideal but at the very least would like some **closure**.

Comment: When you wrote "12 lettered seed phrase", did you mean 12 **word** seed phrase?

Comment: My blunder, thanks

Answer (score 1):

To check your derivation path manually, you can use a tool such as [[https://iancoleman.io/bip39/]](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/). After selecting BIP44 for P2PKH address in the derivation path, the tool will display all the addresses that can be generated from your seed. Simply identify the address that corresponds to your specific needs, and use the corresponding derivation path when importing your seed into any wallet.

*Note this tool can be used offline mode, read the insturction in the web.

Comment: already tried, didn't work out